# What field does the Docker tag relate to in RFC 5424

Tags: docker, syslog, rsyslog

My Docker syslog tags are being truncated at what seems to be 32 characters. When I look at RFC 5424 I am not sure which field it is. Anyone know? I am trying to verify the allowed length the tag can be.

```
Apr 19 06:43:05 ord-nodecore-prd-01 docker/core_sql_event_processor_ha[1207]: 2016-04-19T06:43:05.265Z [sqlEventHandler] Event '3c5e1a15-f8a1-4bfa-b2fa-2e54b2a5fbaa' resulted in 0 relevant application events
```

Becomes:

```
<30>Apr 19 06:43:05 ord-nodecore-prd-01 docker/core_sql_event_processor_ 2016-04-19T06:43:05.265Z [sqlEventHandler] Event '3c5e1a15-f8a1-4bfa-b2fa-2e54b2a5fbaa' resulted in 0 relevant application events
```

Note the tag, docker/core_sql_event_processor_ha[1207]:

Here is the RFC link: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#page-9

I am thinking it is the 'SD-Name' but it may be 'APP-Name'. No idea.

Comment: This seems to indicate its APP-Name, https://blog.logentries.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

Your example has nothing to do with RFC5424, and looks more like RFC3164 (which is not a standard, but a collection of older best practices).
Please read this: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#appendix-A.1
then search for 'TAG ' - in essence, RFC5424 does not have a TAG field as such.

I am not familiar with Docker logging, but if I read
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#syslog-options
, then check `syslog-format` - it seems that the format can be specified, also to be like `rfc5424micro` which I would recommend, but seems like in your case it is not configured like that.